# Mixed Regular Expression for Numbers with different digits, optional letters and dots

Tags: java, android, regex

I am working on an Android app for Handheld Scan devices that should scan different Types of QR Codes; these QR Codes can contain different variations of digits, letters, dots and plus Signs; as I am not an expert for Regular Expressions, any hints or help would be very much appreciated.

The Regular Expression(s) should match the occurences of the following digits, letters, dots and plus signs:

```
1256+70

1235.B+70

1256+70+DB

1235.B+70+DB

1256+70+DB2020-123

1235.B+70+DB2020-123

1256+0+DB2020-123

1235.B+0+DB2020-123
```

The number range of the first four digits can be [100-99999].[A-Z]

I came up with the following Regular Expressions

```
    [0-9]{4}

    [0-9]{3,6}$.?[A-Z]?+[0-9]+DB[0-9]{4}-[0-9]]

    [0-9]{3,6}$.?[A-Z]?+[0-9]

    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].+DB

    \b\d{3,6}\b

    [0-9]{3,6}$.?[A-Z]?+[0-9]+DB[0-9]{4}-[0-9]]

    [0-9]{3,6}$.?[A-Z]?+[0-9]

    [0-9]{3,6}$.?[A-Z]?+[0-9]
```

but they are not covering all of the possible combinations and missing out a lot of options - hence any help or hints would be very much appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely there is one regex that covers all QR codes? And further to that, why do you need a regex at all? It isn't your job to validate them. They already exist.

Comment: Perhaps like this `^[1-9]\d\d\d{0,2}(?:\.[A-Z])?\+\d+(?:\+DB(?:\d{4}-\d{3})?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/G36JN2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the example data, one option could be using 1 regex with specific and optional parts:

```
^[1-9]\d{2,4}(?:\.[A-Z])?\+\d+(?:\+DB(?:\d{4}-\d{3})?)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[1-9]\d{2,4}` Match from 100 till 99999
- `(?:\.[A-Z])?` Optionally match `.` and a char A-Z
- `\+\d+` match `+` and 1+ digits *(or use `\d{1,2}` to match 1 or 2 digits)*
- `(?:` Non cpature group

  - `\+DB(?:\d{4}-\d{3})?` match `+` and DB and optionally match 4 digits `-` and 3 digits
- `)?`  Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bpiajm/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "^[1-9]\\d{2,4}(?:\\.[A-Z])?\\+\\d+(?:\\+DB(?:\\d{4}-\\d{3})?)?$";
```

Comment: @user15358848 You can also write it like that of course:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[1-9][0-9]{2,5}[.0-9A-Z+\-]+
```

will work.